# Why does a user-provided constructor allow for instantiation of a const class instance?

Tags: c++

Here is an [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization#Default_initialization_of_a_const_object) from cpp reference.

```
struct T1 { int mem; };

struct T2
{
    int mem;
    T2() { } // "mem" is not in the initializer list
};

int main()
{
    //  const T1 t1;  // error: const class with implicit default ctor
    T1 t1;            // class, calls implicit default ctor
    const T2 t2;      // const class, calls the user-provided default ctor
                      // t2.mem is default-initialized (to indeterminate value)
}
```

In the example,  `//  const T1 t1;  // error: const class with implicit default ctor` makes sense because if that was allowed then it would make `mem` an uninitialized const member that cant be changed.

But the third one,

```
 const T2 t2;      // const class, calls the user-provided default ctor
                   // t2.mem is default-initialized (to indeterminate value)
```

It says, `// const class, calls the user-provided default ctor`. Now this doesn't make sense to me because the constructor still isn't initializing mem. Then it goes on to say `// t2.mem is default-initialized`. How?

I would understand this if the constructor initialized `mem`. Something like:

```
T2(int mem = 0) : mem(mem) { }
```

The original user defined constructor in the cpp reference example does absolutely nothing and still initializes `mem`. How? Is it just a rule I need to remember or is there something else happening?

Comment: Remember that `T2`'s constructor definition might be in another translation unit.

Comment: I think the examples they provide are self contained.

Comment: I get a warning only on MSVC, and an error suggesting -fpermissive on gcc. I'd be curious for some expert to tell if the language requires a error, here, or not.

Comment: @user16038533 - They are, but the rules apply to the general case, not a narrow example. A user defined constructor (even if given inline) is a "black box" as far as the rules are concerned. The only exception is if you want to make the type literal and usable in constant expressions.

Comment: I meant, with `const T1 t1;` compiler knows that `mem` is not initialized. For `const T2 t2;`, it depends of definition of user defined constructor (which might be not visible), so language rule should works for both cases.

Comment: initialization is confusing. In `T2`s constructor `mem` is default initialized, which for an `int` means it is not initialized ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does a user-provided constructor allow for instantiation of a const class instance?

Because the default constructor is responsible for initialisation of the object.

Sure, in this case the constructor fails to initialise the member in this case, but the compiler cannot generally know that whether it does that. Because a user defined constructor is used, it *may* make sense and thus there is no reason to disallow that.

> The original user defined constructor in the cpp reference example does absolutely nothing and still initializes mem

It "default initialises" which is what happens when you don't initialise something.

Comment: So in other words, if a user defined constructor is present in a class, then all of its members are default initialized?

Comment: @user16038533 If you don't have a user defined constructor and you default initialise an instance, then all members will be default initialised. If you define a user defined default construcor and default initialise an instance, then that user defined constructor will be called. If you don't initialise any members in the member init list of the user defined constructor (and there are no default member initialisers), then they will be default initialised, just like in the case of no user defined default constructor.

Comment: Does the standard requires an error to be emitted if there only the implicit default constructor, or is a warning enough ?

Comment: @Jeffrey The standard never requires a compilation error in any case. If program is ill-formed, then standard requires it to issue a diagnostic message (unless explicitly stated otherwise in the standard) and is allowed to refuse to compile the program.

Comment: thanks for correctly my lingo. Is a program that relies on the default implicit constructor to init a const object ill-formed? is what I meant to ask. Because my MSVC seems able to compile it, while just producing a helpful warning.

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes, it's ill-formed. MSVC's behaviour is conforming to the standard because it issued a diagnostic message. Intentionally compiling an ill-formed program is called a language extension.